# Camera showing a line in the distance

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, camera, rendering

I really don´t know how to explain it good, the problem is the rendering of the camera, i'm showing it in the photo.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG4Oc.jpg)

Do you know what that is?

Comment: Mipmapping artifacts.

Comment: The textures was in point filtering, that was the issue.